# Using decision tree for unsupervised discretization?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, cart, binning

I want to discretize a continuous variable $X$ into a given number of classes $k$ (assume for simplicity that $k$ is even).

Decision trees (and related methods) are already used to discretize a variable in a supervised context, but I find nothing regarding decision trees in an unsupervised context (in the sense of [Kohavi et al.](http://ai.stanford.edu/%7Eronnyk/disc.pdf)). The idea is simply to build a regression tree model where the target and the input are the same, i.e. $y=X$. This should result in subgroups (from which I derive the classes) which maximize the between-group variance.

Yet, I feel like I'm missing something obvious since the method is not being used anywhere. The module `sklearn.preprocessing` proposes methods based on K-means, on the distribution of the variable, on the range of the variable but nothing regarding decision trees.

*Edit*. Here is an example : Suppose I'm trying to predict the popularity of a set of articles for a press company. The popularity is captured by the number of shares on social networks, so it's a continuous variable. The company wants me to discretize the number of shares in order to get 4 classes (from very popular to not popular at all) before moving on to prediction because it is more readable from a business point of view. Can decision trees be of any help in achieving this goal?

Comment: Please say more in your question about why you want to do this. It is generally [not a good idea](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/68834/28500).

Comment: CART (classification and regression tree) models are known weak learners.  They have bias, they can be misled.  They have issues.  An ensemble of CART models, aka a Random Forest, is a much better tool for avoiding the pathologies of single CART models.  If you are looking for clustering, using gaussian mixtures isn't a bad idea, and should be a built-in.

Comment: Why not bin each continuous variable into 4 categories of equal frequency size? - Why are talking about decision tree which is a supervised method?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the example added to the original question, it seems that you already have data on the "popularity" of the articles. In that case I agree with @ttnphns that the best approach for discretization, if you really have to do it, would be to break up the known continuous "popularity" measure into 4 equal sized groups representing quartiles of the distribution. You rank the cases in order of "popularity" and break them into four equal-sized groups based on the ranks. That "get[s] 4 classes (from very popular to not popular at all)."

I strongly recommend avoiding the discretization as much as possible, however. Even if there needs to be a breakdown into groups to make things "more readable from a business point of view," that shouldn't interfere with the modeling itself if you are trying to predict a continuous measure like "popularity." To make things "readable from a business point of view," you could provide *examples* of prediction performance within those groups. The predictions will be most reliable and the *examples* least misleading, however, if you set up your prediction model to work with the actual "popularity" values as the outcome variable.